# Excel formula: If duplicate found in column B, add a "Y" value in column D

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, excel-2016

Trying to figure out which is the best formula to use for this situation. I have a list of about 15,000 (master) unique Device IDs. I need to compare this list to 8 or 9 other lists of Device IDs. If there's a duplicate (i.e. a device ID is on the master and on the comparison lists), I want to add a "y" to a specific column.

What I'm doing now. I am copying and pasting the comparison lists below the master list column of Device IDs. I am running Conditional Formatting so that if there's a duplicate, the cell is highlighted, and I am adding the "Y" to the column manually. One formula someone provided was the following: `=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,B2)>0,"Y","")`
But this doesn't really work, because it puts "Y" in EVERY column. I would like to to check for a duplicate first. Any ideas? Sorry for this newb question, I UTFSE and am still not sure which formula to use.

[image: current task]

Comment: Your formula should be "greater than 1" ```=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,B2)>1,"Y","")```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use something like this below, add a column to your master list and just put "Y" next to every entry. Then if there's a match for that cell in your other lists it will pull "Y" and if there's no match it will 'appear' blank (although the formula will still be there.

`=iferror(vlookup([cell],[Master List],2,0),"")`

Using your formula you have in your question you have to modify it like so:

`=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,B2)>1,"Y","")` Added 1, since it would need to appear twice for your original approach to show Y.

Comment: I haven't tried your iferror formula, because I'm a bit nervous about making a critical mistake, but your corrected version of the if(countif) formula seems to be working!